# How to reverse foreach $key value PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

My brain is off , I am using foreach index to assign z-index to elements but I need it to go in reverse order. The last one should be 0 the first one should have highest z-index;

```
foreach ($array as $key => $layer){


        // css z-index: $key reversed 
}
```

any help is appreciated

**EDIT:**
well , everyone is going nuts because I asked this question but I did not look for  array_reverse thus I posted a question

I asked how to reverse the **$key** and only one who understood was  Sergey Krivov

Comment: This really should be closed. A simple internet search for "how to reverse array in php" would give the answer.

Comment: @TechJS Looking at all the timestamps, Jonathan M's was submitted first ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah you right ;) but i dont get why i got downvoted ;(

Comment: @TechJS that was not my downvote, somebody must have done that because of your comment up there. Especially the part about *ACCEPT MY ANSWER plz*

Comment: @TechJS, I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing it was the "plz". StackOverflow values correct spelling. ;-)

Comment: @JonathanM ok. got it ;)

Comment: @TechJS: Or maybe because JS is in your username.

Comment: well someone's going around downvoting all the answers given, *dafuq?* and no explanation in some, if not all.

Comment: @TechJS, again...spelling. ;-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver what is the point? I love JS! that have nothing to do with my second love! (php) I have a third lover (C#) and Im gonna love python ..:D

Comment: @TechJS now now, don't be sore ;-) "kind of unclear", yes; "shitty", no. Edit and as per their edit, see? I was right. *"but I did not ask specifically how to reverse an array thus I posted a question"* - You're welcome to flag the question though; that's your choice. However, I doubt it will be accepted if you ask to "remove" the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- bud , I edited and flagged , I thought I was clear enough with the comment inside the loop , but everyone is going nuts and downvoting each other. seems like tolerance here is completely gone.

Comment: @Benn yeah, I know (people are or can be strange animals). I didn't think it was a bad question (I did not downvote it, voted to close as unclear I will admit, but not downvoted), a tad unclear but I'm sure that more experienced coders than myself (with arrays) picked up on that (I kind of suck at arrays) ;-) *Cheers* - Edit: My tolerance is rather high as is my patience. After all, one has to, if one grows "cactus", which I do. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$layercount = count($array);
foreach ($array as $key => $layer){
    // css z-index: $key reversed
    $zIndex = $layercount - 1 - $key;
}
```

Comment: Off by 1: `$zIndex = count($array) - 1 - $key;`

Comment: If you store the array count as `$layercount = count($array)` so you're not constantly calculating the length, I like this solution because it doesn't involve a complete array manipulation, and it's a bit clever.

Comment: this is what I was asking for , not reverse array , but everyone is downvoting. good one bud

Comment: Yes, clever but only works for sequential ascending keys.

Comment: Excellent, works it perfect.

Answer (score 5):

Use `array_reverse()`:

```
$my_reversed_array = array_reverse($my_original_array);
foreach ($my_reversed_array as $key => $layer) {
    ...
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Answer (score 3):

Another method of reversing the order of the array keys is to use PHP's [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to reindex the array with keys reversed by [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), like so:

```php
$data = array_combine( array_reverse(array_keys($data)) , $data );
```

This reassigns the array keys as a reversed array of the original keys.

INPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
    [4] => five
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [4] => one
    [3] => two
    [2] => three
    [1] => four
    [0] => five
)
```

[View a demonstration here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc83eaf21371bb705595ec2e926c93eb3edc427e).

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the array?

```
foreach (array_reverse($array) as $key => $layer){
        // css z-index: $key reversed 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use PHP built-in function: `array_reverse`

INPUT:

```
$my_array = Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
    [4] => five
)
```

.

.

If you call `array_reverse($my_array);`, then the OUTPUT will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => five
    [1] => four
    [2] => three
    [3] => two
    [4] => one
)
```

.

But if you call `array_reverse($my_array, TRUE);`, then the OUTPUT will be:

```
Array
(
    [4] => five
    [3] => four
    [2] => three
    [1] => two
    [0] => one
)
```

.

.

.

As stated in the documentation:

`array_reverse ( array $array [, bool $preserve_keys = FALSE ] ) : array`

```
array
  The input array.

preserve_keys
  If set to TRUE numeric keys are preserved. Non-numeric keys are not affected by this setting and will always be preserved.
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Answer (score -2):

Use `array_reverse`:

```
<?php
$array = array_reverse($array);
foreach ($array as $key => $layer){


        // css z-index: $key reversed 
}
?>
```

Comment: if `associative array`, then yes, the `$key` will be reversed too... but if `normal array`, the `$key` will not be reversed.